# Pressure-Volume Diagram

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, volume, phase-diagram

Why does pressure start off high in the Pressure-Volume Diagram starting from a compressed liquid to a super heated vapor?

Noting that the temperature is constant in the process,I can't seem to understand why it would start at a high pressure going to lower pressure.

Meanwhile, I can understand the Temperature-Volume Diagram why temperature started of at a low value then increases eventually.

It seems that I am confused at the idea of changing saturation temperature and pressure. On the other hand, I understand the idea that boiling point and melting point temperatures can change if we are given with different pressures.

[image]

Comment: Can you at least accept that, in the superheated region, at constant temperature, if volume increases, pressure decreases?  (Think ideal gas law)

Comment: Is it like a universal law? I just thought that there might be an important reason behind the relationship.

Comment: Are you asking about the applicability of the ideal gas law , or are you asking about its derivation?

Comment: "*I can't seem to understand why it would start at a high pressure going to lower pressure.*" I don't understand your question. The right graph clearly shows pressure starting **low**, then going **high** and then going **low** again. What do you mean when you say that pressure starts high?

Answer (score 2):

Because liquids are in general much less compressible than gases, meaning that a small reduction in volume requires a big increase in pressure.